# runnig duende identity server in docker

Tags: .net, docker, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have microservice application in .Net 6 and I containerize all of the services and run them in https (localhost) . but the problem is Taht the other services can not find the identity server . and all of the container is up and running . and I should say that I use JWT token to authorize other applications from the identity server

when run the containers I expect that the services see the identity successfully